# How to run .net core application in batch file

Tags: .net-core, scheduled-tasks

I am writing a .net core app to run as a job to sync data. I have added dotnet.exe command to Path and it works well When I run the app directly in command line.

I have deployed the app to server and write a batch script(job.bat) to run it as below.

```
cd D:\the\folder\where\the\app\locate
dotnet TheJobToBeExecuted.dll
```

I want to run the job every 5 min, So I add the batch to Task Scheduler with the script below

```
schtasks /create /tn "Job" /tr "D:\the\folder\where\the\batch\locate\job.bat" /sc minute /mo 5
```

But the job doesn't work as expected. Then I alter the **job.bat** as below to see what happened.

```
cd D:\the\folder\where\the\app\locate
dotnet TheJobToBeExecuted.dll
pause
```

The Messages showed as below

```
Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
```

But I already install dotnet and added it to path on server, also I can run the app directly on server cmd.

Am I missing something? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have resolved this issue.

There are two versions of dotnet core runtime in my machine. One is in "Program Files (x86)" folder and another is in "Program Files" directory. They are both included in path environment.

I moved "c:\Program Files\dotnet\" ahead of the "C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\" in path environment. I works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please run "get-command dotnet" in powershell and check the results with your environment variables path.

[image]

Comment: got same result except Version.